# How do I access values from string array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Can anyone help me please? I'm really stuck.
I need to be able to access the values of the following in the post method (the name and the qty) so that I can add them to the model. (the inputs will be generated by JavaScript

```
        <div id="ingredientsMainContainer">
            <input type="text" name="Ingredient[0][Name]" />
            <input type="text" name="Ingredient[0][Qty]" />

            <input type="text" name="Ingredient[1][Name]" />
            <input type="text" name="Ingredient[1][Qty]" />
        </div>
```

The list can be unlimited, so it could go up to Ingredient[10] or more.

I can access like this:

```
var test = Request.Form["Ingredient[0][Name]"];
var test2 = Request.Form["Ingredient[1][Name]"];
```

but I need to loop through all Ingredient[] inputs for the Name and Qty.

Thanks

Comment: if your posting a list from javascript to some kind of webserver. Why not use Json and the built in tools for parsing?

Answer (score 0):

A for-loop and string concatenation should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    // $"Ingredient[{i}][Name]" is the same as "Ingredient[" + i + "][Name]"
    Request.Form[$"Ingredient[{i}][Name]"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I be able to find out how many Ingredients[] had been submitted? I've tried: string[] ingredients = Request.Form["Ingredient[]"]; var len = ingredients.Length but that doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: maybe use a very high number and wrap the above code in a try/catch statement. Then, on first IndexError, you know you've got all ingredients. But there might be a better way, like sending a number with JavaScript and using that with the error handling?